# Camel HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE setup

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to handle exception in my route which was thrown by my soap endpoint with onException. I need to implement some custom logic to map SOAP exeption to certain HTTP response headers.

When I use

```
 setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(502)).
```

directly in my route definition, the header is setup fine. However my custom logic cannot be implemented.

I tried to setup header in processor

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, "502");
```

but it is ignored and system concuming my resoponse recieves HTTPCode = 200.
Full routing code is below:

```
 rest().post("/mypost")                
            .type(MyRequest.class)
            .outType(MyResponse.class)
            .route().routeId("rst_myrest")
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,"recived: ${body}")
            .to("direct:drt_addData")
            .endRest();

 onException(ServiceException.class).
            handled(true).
            setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(502)). //i remove this line when using processor header setup
            onExceptionOccurred(serviceExceptionProcessor).
            marshal(new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson)).end();


public class ServiceExceptionProcessor implements Processor{
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        ServiceException request = exchange.getException(ServiceException.class);
        //preparing body, etc
        exchange.getOut().setBody(message, Errors.class);       
        // some logic for defining header response code
        // for example response code is 502
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, "502");

    }
}
```

How can I setup header in processor? How does header setup work?

Comment: You should use exchange.getIn() and not getOut()

Comment: Great, it works! I wonder why

Comment: Because no "out" exchange has been created. Only "in" exchanges exist. In 99% of cases you don't need to worry about the out exchange.